# Database design for selecting a main element from a list

Tags: database-design

A user has a list of books, but only 1 book can be displayed on his profile as he should select it as his favourite book. How do I design my schema to set a book as being 'the' book?

If I have a field `IsFavourite` in the book entity, then all books can be marked as favourite. If I'm setting a favourite on 1, I have to retrieve his favourite book and unmark it as favourite (3 database calls).

If I have a preference entity that has a reference to a book, I can just set that book to be the favourite;

```
User -< Preferences >- Book >- User
User -< Book
```

How do you accomplish things like these? Is there another method I'm missing? Which is the best? I'm using code-first entity framework, so I code my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three tables/models

```
Users
Books
UserBooks (join table, user id and book id, and favorite flag)
```

There is a one to many association between users and books.

Instead of the favorite flag in the third table you could have a preferences model with reference to users (and their favorite book) but it depends on what other things you want to put there as to whether that is advisable or how it would look.